# Gradle - Copy folder into jar

Tags: gradle

In my gradle.build I have the following code in order to copy the content of a folder into the jar during the build process

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["build/swagger-ui-myapp/"]
        }
        output.resourcesDir = "build/resources/main/swagger-ui-myapp"
    }
}
```

The content of the folder ends up in the `BOOT-INF/classes/` folder in the jar. But I don't want the content of the folder in that directory, I want the files to be inside the original folder, so I want them inside `BOOT-INF/classes/swagger-ui-myapp`. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't change the resources to do that. instead, I would just configure the bootJar task:

```
bootJar {
  dependsOn(taskWhichGeneratesTheBuildSwaggerUiMyapp)
  bootInf {
    into("classes/swagger-ui-myapp") {
      from("$buildDir/swagger-ui-myapp")
    }
  }
}
```